# docker mongoose error invalid database name

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, mongoose, docker-compose

I'm trying to connect my MongoDB running on docker to local MongoDB to access the database, the issue is when I start my application it shows connected to Database but at the time of calling my API's it throws an error saying invalid database name.[image: Error show in terminal]

[image: env file used]

[image: docker-compose file]

Comment: Better to post code as text instead of screenshots

Comment: according to error, your db name has unnecessary quote symbol, probably you need to remove quotes from your yml, like: `DATABASE_URL=${DATABASE_URL}`

Comment: The `micro` database doesn't exist, and it won't exist until you create a collection on it.